# How to install extra packages in Google Colaboratory's VM?

Tags: google-colaboratory

I'm playing with Google Colaboratory, and noticed right off the bat that `tqdm` is not pre-installed. Is there any way to install additional packages?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yup. You can use `pip` or `apt` to install packages as needed.

One example for `pip` is in the [welcome notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/notebook#fileId=/v2/external/notebooks/welcome.ipynb&forceEdit=true&sandboxMode=true&scrollTo=FlQq0SUepQbd):

```
!pip install -q matplotlib-venn
from matplotlib_venn import venn2
venn2(subsets = (3, 2, 1))
```

An example for `apt` is in the [snippets](https://colab.research.google.com/notebook#fileId=/v2/external/notebooks/snippets/importing_libraries.ipynb&scrollTo=kDn_lVxg3Z2G):

```
!apt update && apt install -y libfluidsynth1
```

In the case of tdqm, `!pip install tqdm` worked for me.

Comment: do you know how to build a package after using `git clone` in google colaboratory?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, to install tqdm you can use

```
!pip install tqdm
```

Hope this helps.